# Odoo 10: Cant call my python function from menu item

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Here it is my view.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
  <data>
<record id="view_sim" model="ir.actions.server">

            <field name="name">Details</field>
             <field name="model_id" ref="model_test" />   
            <field name="condition">True</field>

            <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>

            <field name="state">code</field>

            <field name="code">self.on_test()</field>

    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="view_sim">
        <field name="name">Details</field>
        <field 
         name="res_model">test</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="limit">100</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="domain">[]</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create new
            </p>
        </field>
</record>


    <!-- Top menu item -->
     <menuitem id="root.menu_root" name="card"/>
     <!-- menu categories -->
        <menuitem id="sim" name="Sim" parent="root.menu_root" action="view_sim"/>

  </data>
</odoo>
```

Here is my python function in models.py :

```
def on_test(self):
          _logger.error("test")
```

I am not able to call this function when i click on my menuitem.I get an error :

```
ValueError: <type 'exceptions.NameError'>: "name 'self' is not defined" while evaluating
u'self.on_test()
```

Is it the right way to call the function in odoo 10? How can i call my function or define self in views.xml?

Comment: Why do you have two records with the same `id` (xml id) in your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `ir.actions.server` or simple Server Actions in the technical part of Odoo. It has some interesting advantage for beginners: a little documentation. Following is a copy from Odoo 10 and shows the little documentation you get on creating a python code server action:

```py
# Available variables:
#  - time, datetime, dateutil, timezone: Python libraries
#  - env: Odoo Environement
#  - model: Model of the record on which the action is triggered
#  - record: Record on which the action is triggered if there is one, otherwise None
#  - records: Records on which the action is triggered if there is one, otherwise None
#  - log : log(message), function to log debug information in logging table
#  - Warning: Warning Exception to use with raise
# To return an action, assign: action = {...}
```

And you're coming from a menu, so Odoo does not know about any records. Just use `model.on_test()` as PROTOCOL already has written. You should also decorate you method with `@api.model` to tell Odoo that there aren't any records involved in the call of this method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
Instead of

```
<field name="code">self.on_test()</field>
```

change to

```
<field name="code">model.on_test()</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

Useful link where you could find the documentation of the available options in the evaluation context of Odoo Server Actions

http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/actions.html#reference-actions-server-context